# How to save on disk file generated with spatie/browsershot

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

In my laravel 5.8/blade/jQuery v3.3.1 app with https://github.com/spatie/browsershot plugin I managed
in my kubuntu 18 to upload my file with path

```
 $save_to_file= '/home/username/Downloads/file.pdf';
 Browsershot::html(htmlspecialchars_decode($pdf_content))
     ->showBackground()
     ->save($save_to_file);
```

But to run it without error I had to run in my console :

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/username/Downloads/
```

otherwize I got error access permission

1) I wonder if there is a way to escape this error on client's OS, as I can not run

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/username/Downloads/
```

on client's site.
I search OS independently decision

2) Can you advice some Javascript/Jquery script to open "SaveAs" dialog for choosing of saving location? 
And maybe somehow to check if app has not write access to info user?